# Alternative to Heron's Formula , through Proof by Pythagorean Theorem.

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, pythagorean-triples

(This works for all triangles)

The area ($A$) of a right triangle, can be  given by the inner radius ($r$) multiplied by the semi perimeter ($s$), where $r = \frac12(a + b- c)$ and $s = \frac12(a + b + c)$.

$$A = \tfrac14\left(a+ b - c\right)\left(a + b + c\right)$$

Proof through Pythagorean Theorem:

$$\begin{align}
\tfrac12ab &= \tfrac14\left(a+ b - c)(a + b + c\right) \\[8pt] 
2ab &= (a+ b - c)(a + b + c)\\[4pt]
&= \left(a+ b)^2 - c^2\right)\\[4pt]
&= \left(a^2 + 2ab + b^2 - c^2\right)\\[4pt]
0 &= a^2 + b^2 - c^2\\[4pt]
c^2 &= a^2 + b^2
\end{align}$$

Comment: *"n is the nth term of a sequence ..."* This is a bit confusing; also, irrelevant, as you never *use* $n$ in your discussion. Listing the primitive Pythagorean triples "in increasing order of $a$" doesn't seem to matter, either. As I see it, you could eliminate the bulk of your text and write, simply:  "Given a Pythagorean triple $(a,b,c)$ with $a<b<c$, and $k$ such that $(a/k,b/k,c/k)$ is a *primitive* Pythagorean triple, the area of the corresponding right triangle is given by [formula] when $a/k$ is even, and [formula] when $a/k$ is odd." Adding examples to show plausibility would help.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, :)

Comment: @BreadSpooner: Glad to help. :) If nothing else, don't write $(a+b+c/2)$ and $(a-2/2)$ and $(a-1/2)$ when you *mean* $(a+b+c)/2$ and $(a-2)/2$ and $(a-1)/2$.

Comment: I would expect a scaling factor like $k$ to be squared in the formula for an area.

Comment: @BreadSpooner  if we arrange triples into $(8,15,17)$ etc. then the formula for their generation must be split into two versions. It is simpler to have A always odd and B always even. There is another formula which generates fewer "multiples" than Euclid's and still generates all primitives. It generates only and all triples where GCD(A,B,C) is an odd square and groups triples into distinct sets. For example in $Set_2,\space$ $GCD(15,8,17)=1$, $GCD(21,20,29)=1$,  $GCD(27,39,45)=9$,  $GCD(33,56,65)=1$,  $GCD(39,80,89)=1\cdots $. Let me know if you would like to hear more about it.

Comment: I have 2 versions, odd and evens for my formula but I found an error which I am currently fixing, but tell me more

Comment: @BreadSpooner: By your last example, calculations don't use the original Pyth triple but rather the *primitive-ized* triple. So, formulas $(1)$ don't capture your intent: you should substitute-in $a\to a/k$, etc, and simplify. For $a/k$ even, you'd have $$\frac14k^2\left(\frac{a}{k}-2\right)\left(\frac{a}{k}+\frac{b}{k}+\frac{c}{k}\right)\quad\to\quad \frac14(a-2k)(a+b+c)$$The odd case becomes $\frac14(a-k)(a+b+c)$. Even so, your formulas remain incorrect. Hint: "The" way to express the target area with a required factor of $a+b+c$ also has $a$, $b$, & $c$ in the other factor (no $k$s needed).

Comment: You have made a large number of edits since you posted this question yesterday.  Large numbers of edits repeatedly bump this question to the top of the queue, and have the potential to invalidate answers which have already been provided.  Please think carefully about what you want to ask before you ask it, and then try to get it right the first time.  If you want to test out formatting, there is a [dedicated sandbox](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370/formatting-sandbox) on the meta site.

Comment: @BreadSpooner: You're getting there. :) But there shouldn't be a $k$ in your area formula. It's just $A=\tfrac14(a+b+c)(a+b-c)$. (And this formula works regardless of whether $a$, $b$, and $c$ are integers.) Notice that, although hypotenuse $c$ is a distinguished largest side, the order of legs $a$ and $b$ is irrelevant and needn't be declared. Also notice that the formula now borrows *two* factors from Heron. (Also-also, it's provable from the inradius of a right triangle being $r=\tfrac12(a+b-c)$, in which case your formula reverts to $A=rs$ where $s:=\tfrac12(a+b+c)$ is the semiperimeter.)

Comment: I  figured that out only a few minutes ago :), thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If we are dealing with Pythagorean triples it pays to look at Euclid' formula, shown here as

$$A=m^2-k^2\qquad B=2mk\qquad C=m^2+k^2$$

Heron's formula is great for finding area of an arbitrary triangle, but there is no need for it if we are dealing with Pythagorean triples. Instead, we can straight to the area/perimeter ratio. These occur in multiples of 1/2 starting with triangle $(3,4,5)$. To find triples with any such ration (here R-1), we may begin by solving equations for $k$ and testing a define range of m-values to see which, if any, yield integers.

$$\text{Using $F(m,k)$: }\qquad R=\frac{area}{perimeter}=\frac{AB/2P}=\frac{2mk(m^2-k^2)}{2(2m^2+2mk)}=\frac{mk-k^2}{2}
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad $$

\begin{equation}
R=\frac{mk-k^2}{2}\quad\implies k=\frac{m\pm\sqrt{m^2-8R}}{2}\\
\text{for}\quad \big\lceil\sqrt{8R}\big\rceil\le m \le (2R+1)
\end{equation}
The lower limit insures that $k\in\mathbb{N}$. The upper limit ensures that $m> k$.
$$R=1\implies  \lceil\sqrt{8}\rceil=3\le m \le (2+1)=3 \qquad\land\qquad   m\in\{ 3\}\implies k\in\{ 2,1\}$$
$$F(3,2)=(5,12,13)\quad\land\quad \frac{30}{30}=1\qquad\qquad\qquad F(3,1)=(8,6,10)\quad\land\quad \frac{24}{24}=1$$

It appears that $R=1$ for perfect triangles but any ratio can be found this way. for example, $R=1.5$ yields
\begin{align*}
R=1.5 &\rightarrow \space (7,24,25)\quad\space\space (15,8,17)\\
R=2.0 &\rightarrow  \space (9,40,41)\quad\space (12,16,20)\quad (24,10,26)\\
R=2.5 &\rightarrow  (11,60,61)\quad (35,12,37)\\
R=3.0 &\rightarrow    (13,84,85)\quad (16,30,34)\quad (21,20,29)\quad (48,14,50)
\end{align*}

Comment: It's easier to solve $R = \frac{mk-k^2}{2}$ for $m$ in terms of $k$, getting $m = \frac{2R}{k} + k$.

Comment: @Misha Lavrov The problem with solving for $m$ is identifying a finite range of k-values. Since $m>k$ in Euclid's formula, my solution is to derive  the low limit  from $k=m/2$ and the high limit from $k=1$. (The lowest possible $m$ for a given area "size" occurs when $k$ is halfway between $1$ and $m$.)

$R=\frac{m(m/2)-(m/2)^2}{2} \implies R = m^2/8\implies m=\sqrt{8R}\qquad$

$R=\frac{m(1)-(1)^2}{2}\implies m=2R+1$

Comment: A finite range of $k$-values is $k=1, 2, \dots, 2R$ since past that, $\frac{2R}{k}+k$ definitely won't be an integer. If it's feasible to list the divisors of $2R$, we can also do that.

Comment: @Misha Lavrov Lowest k-value is $1$ and the lowest m-value is $2$. I suppose you could work out k-limits assuming the "high" occurs when $m=2k$. This doesn't feel right but that's may be just because I haven't tested it like I have the m-limit. in most of my "solutions", the high limit for m is when $k=m-1$. Here is an attempt with $k=2m$.

$$R=\frac{2k(k)-(k)^2}{2}=R=\frac{(k)^2}{2}\implies k=\sqrt{2R}\implies 1 \le k \le\lfloor\sqrt{2R}\space\rfloor$$

Comment: I don't think $k\le \sqrt{2R}$ is true. Let's try your $R=3$ case again starting with $k$. Then $2R=6$, so we take $k=1,2,3,6$ giving us $m=\frac{6}{1}+1=7$, $m=\frac{6}{2}+2=5$, $m=\frac63+3=5$, and $m=\frac66+6=7$. The pairs $(k,m) \in \{(1,7),(2,5),(3,5),(6,7)\}$ give us $(48,14,50)$, $(21,20,29)$, $(16,30,34)$, and $(13,84,85)$, which are the same four solutions you got. But if we require $k \le \sqrt{2R}$, we miss the last two solutions.

Comment: @Misha Lavrov I remember some kind of confusion years ago when I first developed formulas like this. 

Suppose we let $k=m-1$ as is the upper limit in most of my formulas. Then m=k+1

$$m=k+1\implies R=\frac{m(k)-k^2}{2}=\frac{(k+1)(k)-k^2}{2}=\frac{k}{2}\implies k=2R\implies 1\le k\le 2R$$
This makes sense since k can be as high as $m-1$.